# How do I get google ads on API < 9?

Tags: android, admob

AdMob is only available on api 9 and higher. However other apps on the playstore are using google ads pre 9 how can I get that?

Comment: no naw a day admob is the part of play store lib so change the play  store lib version

Comment: try to chage in playstore Manifest  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

Comment: I think the once having ads are using the standalone admob sdk from which updates are no longer accepted but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

Accept the fact that virtually no one is using API < 9 anymore. It is pretty safe to use API 9 as minimum.
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html

When you target API 9 you can use the latest Google Play services library.